# How to update a program that was manually compiled from source?

Tags: linux, updates, sudo, make

What is the best way to install an update I have manually compiled from source to a program I also previously manually compiled from source?

Should I execute `sudo make uninstall` first and then execute `sudo make install`, or is it enough to execute only `sudo make install`?

Some Makefiles do not provide an uninstall target and when I try I to make an uninstall I recieve the following error:

> make: *** No rule to make target 'uninstall'.  Stop.

Comment: Just replace its binary executables and any dependencies that were updated

Comment: Wouldn't it be time consuming if program had lots of dependencies?

Comment: Yes, it would. This is why package managers are a godsend: the packagers have done the hard work for you.

Comment: @reinierpost Yes, I use them everyday. However, I need to compile some programs like OpenCV, dlib etc. to get latest features and to configure them.

Comment: If you install into `/usr/local` with `stow`, as e.g. described [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/325923/for-convention-in-which-folder-should-i-place-no-installable-applications), you can easily uninstall by just deleting the symlinks with `stow -D`. This works even if your source doesn't support uninstalling via the Makefile (as in your case), or if the uninstall isn't complete (happens often enough). So never install into the normal hierarchy as root directly, leave that to the package managers.

Comment: This is what I do (except I use my own script instead of `stow`, because I didn't know about `stow` when I wrote it). I install software into a version-specific directory and then use my script to symlink it into common paths.That way I can install multiple versions, pick one to use, and uninstall the rest. It becomes hairier when dependencies are involved because dependencies won't be tracked this way. This should be an answer ...

Comment: Well you said compiling manually I take that as your not using a build system

Comment: "Compiling manually" using `stow` will usually be something like `wget https://www.example.com/path/to/foo-1.2.3.tar.gz && tar xvf foo-1.2.3.tar.gz && cd foo-1.2.3 && ./configure --with-path=/usr/local/stow/foo-1.2.3 && make && sudo -u localowner make install && sudo -u localowner stow foo-1.2.3 && cd .. && rm -rf foo-1.2.3.*` (in the absolutely ideal case).